# Unable to Fetch values from XML file using perl

Tags: xml, perl, fetch

Below is the xml file:

```
<Build_details>
  <Release number="1902">
    <Build number="220">
      <OMS>
        <Build_path>ST_OMS_V19021_B220</Build_path>
        <Pc_version>8042.18.01</Pc_version>
      </OMS>
      <OMNI>
        <Build_path>ST_OMNI_V19021_B220</Build_path>
      </OMNI>
    </Build>
  </Release>
  <Release number="1810">
    <Build number="340">
      <OMS>
        <Build_path>ST_OMS_V1810_B340</Build_path>
        <Pc_version>8041.30.01</Pc_version>
      </OMS>
      <OMNI>
        <Build_path>ST_OMNI_V1810_B340</Build_path>
      </OMNI>
    </Build>
  </Release>
  <Release number="1810">
    <Build number="300">
      <OMS>
        <Build_path>ST_OMS_V18102_B300</Build_path>
        <Pc_version>8041.30.01</Pc_version>
      </OMS>
      <OMNI>
        <Build_path>ST_OMNI_V18102_B300</Build_path>
      </OMNI>
    </Build>
  </Release>
</Build_details>
```

I am unable to fetch values for same release number with other build number. Suppose I want to fetch details for release 1810 build 300 it throws empty value. Seems perl script written by me is only working for first occurrence value.

Below is my script written:

```
#!/appl/OMS/perl/bin/perl
=comments
Perl wrapper for parsing the central repository
xml to fetch relevant data of each release

Help Usage : ./parseenv.pl allrel -- to list all versions\
./parseenv.pl <relno> <buildno> <oms/pc/omni>
ex - ./parseenv.pl 1810 300 oms
Date=20180910
=cut

use XML::Smart;
use File::Path qw(make_path remove_tree);

$FILE="/appl/OMS/Build_Details/build_details.xml";

$xml = XML::Smart->new($FILE) || die ("Could not open XML file");
my $relno=$ARGV[0];
my $build=$ARGV[1];

if ( $ARGV[0] =~ "allrel" ) {
    my @release=$xml->{Build_details}->{Release}('[@]','number');
    foreach $i (@release) {
        print "$i\n";
    }
}

if ($ARGV[1] =~ "build") {
    my @build=$xml->{Build_details}->{Release}->('number','eq',"$relno")->{Build}('[@]','number');
    foreach $i (@build) {
        print "$i\n";
    }
}

if ($ARGV[2] =~ "oms") {
    my @oms=$xml->{Build_details}->{Release}->('number','eq',"$relno")->{Build}('number','eq',"$build")->{OMS}->{Build_path};
    print "@oms\n";

}
elsif ($ARGV[2] =~ "pc") {
    my @pc=$xml->{Build_details}->{Release}->('number','eq',"$relno")->{Build}('number','eq',"$build")->{OMS}->{Pc_version};
    print "@pc\n";

}
elsif ($ARGV[2] =~ "omni") {
    my @omni=$xml->{Build_details}->{Release}->('number','eq',"$relno")->{Build}('number','eq',"$build")->{OMNI}->{Build_path};
    print "@omni\n";

}
else {
    print "Please enter 3rd argument"
}
```

Output Details:

Works fine for first occurance

```
$  ./parsebuilddetails.pl 1810 340 pc
8041.30.01
```

Not works for another occurance:

```
$ ./parsebuilddetails.pl 1810 300 pc
```

How can i modify perl script to make it work for all values of build number. It seems i will have to add a loop. But i am not able to understand how it will iterate. Please help :)

Comment: I've fixed some of the indentation in your code. You're welcome, but please consider doing it yourself in the future. Good indentation is one of the most useful tools for understanding code. If you're asking lots of people to read and understand your code, it's useful to make that as easy as possible for them.

Comment: I don't know a lot about XML::Smart, but it seems to me like the functionalities it provides are quite limited and will not properly fit your use case. You will definitely need more than one loop to achieve what you want. 
Would it be possible for you to use a "state-of-the-art" XML parser such as XML::LibXML ? If yes, then I could suggest a solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dave  for indentation :)

Comment: Sure i can try different module to achieve the results ..can you suggest how it can be achieved

Answer (score 0):

Always use strict and warnings pragmas! Just example of XML::LibXML:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl                                                                                                                                                                            

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $xml_string = join '', <DATA>;

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $xml_string);


foreach my $build_node ($dom->findnodes('//Release[@number="1810"]/Build')) {
  print $build_node->to_literal;
}

__DATA__
...place your xml here
```

[Nice tutorial for XML::LibXML](http://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/)